# How to Use Bash to Replace Line by Line with Changing Variable

Tags: string, bash, replace, sed

I am relatively new to Bash, so please forgive my naivete.

I'm effectively trying to label each line in a very large file at the twentieth character, with the label depending on how many times a particular string has been found.  So in a general sense, I'm hoping to iterate through every line in a file and add a non-static variable.

Below is one of my (many) attempts to make it loop through line by line.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    COUNT=0              # Number of TERs encountered -> chain incrementer.
    CHAIN_LET="$(printf \\$(printf '%03o' $((65+$COUNT)) ))"
    PLACE=1


    while read LINE 
    do       
            if [[ "${LINE}" == *TER* ]]
            then
                    COUNT=$(($COUNT + 1))
                    CHAIN_LET="$(printf \\$(printf '%03o' $((65+$COUNT)) ))"
                    # I've been able to confirm that the code counts the instances
                    # properly.


            fi

            sed -e ''$PLACE's/./&'$CHAIN_LET'/19/' <text.pdb >text_out.pdb
            # Tried to ask sed to replace at each line.

            # sed 's/./&'$CHAIN_LET'/19' <text.pdb >text_out.pdb   
            # Doing this replaces the twentieth character at every iteration,
            # rather than at each line.  Basically, this isn't dynamic.            

            PLACE=$(($PLACE + 1))
    done <text.pdb
```

So, for example, I am hoping to turn the following:

```
    This
    Is
    TER
    An
    Example
    TER           
    Of
    A
    File
```

Into:

```
    This        A
    Is          A
    TER         B
    An          B
    Example     B
    TER         C  
    Of          C
    A           C
    File        C
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a job for `awk` or `perl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk` it is much simpler:

```
awk -v s='TER' '$1==s{c++} {printf "%s%s%c\n", $1, OFS, (65+c)}' OFS='\t' file
This    A
Is      A
TER     B
An      B
Example B
TER     C
Of      C
A       C
File    C
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava!

Unfortunately I wasn't quite clear enough.  Most of the file's lines have much longer strings on them, and this way seems to truncate them.  I've been trying to play with the OFS options to no avail.  Do you have any suggestions for inserting the variable you named "c" in between characters?

Comment: Thank you again for the quick response--also unfortunately, I buggered up the comment system and didn't include my question :(

Comment: Try: `awk -v s='TER' '$0~s{c++} {printf "%s%s%c\n", $0, OFS, (65+c)}' OFS='\t' file` If your files are very different from the question feel free to post a new question with a sample of new input data.